# Webpack production mode

Tags: reactjs, webpack

this is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: `[name].bundle.js`,
    chunkFilename: `[name].bundle.js`
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
         new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')


        }
            }),  
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
   ....      }
      })
      ]...
```

};

I set NODE_ENV to production but my website is showing red that mean it is still in development mode. what is wrong?
How i can minifiy my build?

```
  "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.1"
```

[image]

Comment: which version of webpack you're using ?

Comment: @santosh i just updated my question with webpack version

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
webpack -p
```

that should reduces the bundle size and bundle it in production mode.

Comment: This has worked for me multiple times. You can notice how much smaller your bundle file gets as well as the react plugin that will indicate that the website is built in production mode